# How the performance of datastore batch gets compares to ancestor-only queries?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would expect batch gets to be one of the fastest ways to retrieve data from the datastore. How does it compare to a query to get all the entities of a kind that are below an ancestor? Of course, this query does not have any filters or sort orders.

I would expect this query to be as fast as a batch get, because I would think that it does NOT require an index scan, and would only require the retrieval of the entities directly from the entities bigtable. Also, assuming that all the entities in this table are sorted by their keys, the results would be sitting one next the order, all sequentially arranged - which is not a guarantee in a batch get.

Considering both operations retrieve the same amount of entities, in terms of cost, the query would have only +1 read operation when compared to a batch get.

Do my assumptions make any sense? Have you experienced anything that could confirm or deny these assumptions?

I am planning to make heavy use of these queries if I could confirm my expectations. I would organize my models in a hierarchy, and would avoid storing ref's to other entities in a list (for batch gets) - would not have the list size limitation and I could also avoid retrieving a large entity (with a lot of multi-valued properties) in situations not requiring the batch get.

I would really appreciate any comments on that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you actually try it, measure it with appstats and compare then you have an empirical answer for you specific use case.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I was just hoping Nick Johnson, or anyone with more experience, could give a word about this. So that I dont build a test case which succeeds at some naive conditions, but will fail as my data grows.. But I see your point. =)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that any performance difference you observe between ancestor and non-ancestor queries is anything other than coincidental. But sure, set something up do do the measurement. That's a good practice to follow.

Comment: The point about ancestors is that you can associate entities (one-to-many) without using a multi-valued property and also without using an index scan when querying. So, it's not about ancestor vs non-ancestor queries, it's really about ancestor queries vs batch gets.